# Can not interact correctly with buttons on custom listview layout after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list which shows multiple items per row.
Two buttons and four textviews.

I'm using a ArrayAdapter for intigration my custom layout and to fill in the data in each row.

All wanted entrys are shown and i am able to interact with the buttons.
(Each button changes a textview of its row.)

It all works fine until i scrolled down and up again. Than nothing works anymore.
All items are still there, but by clicking the buttons, the text don't change anymore.

(I save all created TextViews in a Vector, because with the position attribute from the getView method i get the position which item i clicked on the list and so i could pick the specitic one from the vector. it works well until as i wrote, i scrolled the list)

Here is the code of my ArrayAdapter

```
public class LocationlistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Location> {

// GUI elements
private Button btnCheckin;
private Button btnExit;
private Vector<TextView> locationList = new Vector<TextView>();
private Vector<TextView> checkInList = new Vector<TextView>();
private Vector<TextView> checkOutList = new Vector<TextView>();
private Vector<TextView> lastVisitList = new Vector<TextView>();

private boolean checkedIn = false;
private int activeListPosition = -1; // selected ListView item

private static LocationTrackingDB mDBHandler;

public LocationlistAdapter(Context context, List<Location> locations) {
    super(context, R.layout.locationlistrow, locations);

    mDBHandler = LocationTrackingDB.getInstance(getContext());
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locationlistrow, null);

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    } else {
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    TextView txtLocationName = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.txtLocationName);
    TextView txtStartTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtStartTime);
    TextView txtEndTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtEndTime);
    TextView txtLastDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtLastDate);

    if (locationList.size() < mDBHandler.getAllLocations().size()) {
        locationList.add(txtLocationName);
        checkInList.add(txtStartTime);
        checkOutList.add(txtEndTime);
        lastVisitList.add(txtLastDate);
    }

    txtLocationName.setText(mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1).getName());
    txtStartTime.setText(mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1)
            .getStartTime());
    txtEndTime.setText(mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1).getEndTime());
    txtLastDate
            .setText(mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1).getLastVisit());

    btnCheckin = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckIn);
    btnExit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

    btnCheckin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!checkedIn && activeListPosition == -1) {
                checkedIn = true;
                activeListPosition = position;

                Location tmpLocation = mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1);

                SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date currentTime = new Date();
                checkInList.elementAt(position).setText(
                        time.format(currentTime));
                lastVisitList.elementAt(position).setText(
                        date.format(currentTime));
                checkOutList.elementAt(position).setText("waiting ...");

                tmpLocation.setStartTime(time.format(currentTime));
                tmpLocation.setLastVisit(date.format(currentTime));

                mDBHandler.updateLocation(tmpLocation);
            }
        }
    });

    btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkedIn && activeListPosition == position) {
                Location tmpLocation = mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1);

                checkedIn = false;
                activeListPosition = -1;

                SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date currentTime = new Date();
                checkOutList.elementAt(position).setText(
                        time.format(currentTime));

                tmpLocation.setEndTime(time.format(currentTime));
                tmpLocation.setLastVisit(date.format(currentTime));

                mDBHandler.updateLocation(tmpLocation);
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
    }
}
```

Does anybody has a clue why this is happening? Or how i could do this a better way which should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the convertView(view in your case) that comes in the argument of getView function like:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
View v=view;
if(v==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locationlistrow, null);
}

...
...
}
```

Also try to use this adapter code:

```
public class LocationlistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Location> {

    // GUI elements
    private Button btnCheckin;
    private Button btnExit;

    private boolean checkedIn = false;
    private int activeListPosition = -1; // selected ListView item

    private static LocationTrackingDB mDBHandler;

    public LocationlistAdapter(Context context, List<Location> locations) {
        super(context, R.layout.locationlistrow, locations);

        mDBHandler = LocationTrackingDB.getInstance(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = view;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locationlistrow, null);
        }
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        } else {
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        final TextView txtLocationName = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.txtLocationName);
        final TextView txtStartTime = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStartTime);
        final TextView txtEndTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtEndTime);
        final TextView txtLastDate = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.txtLastDate);

        txtLocationName.setText(mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1).getName());
        txtStartTime.setText(mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1)
                .getStartTime());
        txtEndTime.setText(mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1).getEndTime());
        txtLastDate
                .setText(mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1).getLastVisit());

        btnCheckin = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckIn);
        btnExit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

        btnCheckin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!checkedIn && activeListPosition == -1) {
                    checkedIn = true;
                    activeListPosition = position;

                    Location tmpLocation = mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1);

                    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    Date currentTime = new Date();
                    txtLocationName.setText(time.format(currentTime));
                    txtLastDate.setText(date.format(currentTime));
                    txtEndTime.setText("waiting ...");

                    tmpLocation.setStartTime(time.format(currentTime));
                    tmpLocation.setLastVisit(date.format(currentTime));

                    mDBHandler.updateLocation(tmpLocation);
                }
            }
        });

        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkedIn && activeListPosition == position) {
                    Location tmpLocation = mDBHandler.getLocation(position + 1);

                    checkedIn = false;
                    activeListPosition = -1;

                    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    Date currentTime = new Date();
                    txtEndTime.setText(time.format(currentTime));

                    tmpLocation.setEndTime(time.format(currentTime));
                    tmpLocation.setLastVisit(date.format(currentTime));

                    mDBHandler.updateLocation(tmpLocation);
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it...

So easy and totaly logical...

Now i'm asking myself, why i started to use those vectors ... 

Thank you very much :)